# Problems while using partial views in Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with express js. here i am using views and partial views. i am facing an error while trying to access partials views. following is my code for view profile.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <% include partials/header %>
    <h1>this an ejx profile</h1>
    <h2>You have accessd profile of <%= person %> </h2>

</body>

</html>
```

My header.ejs file looks like this.

```
<!-- views/partials/header.ejs -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
                EJS Is Fun
            </a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

i am getting following error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in
>   C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\views\profile.ejs while
>   compiling ejs
>
> If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
>   https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an
>   async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
>       at new Function ()
>       at Template.compile (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:626:12)
>       at Object.compile (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:366:16)
>       at handleCache (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:215:18)
>       at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:16)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:459:10)
>       at View.render (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Xeeshan\Desktop\Node.js\NDBMS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)

this line  `<% include partials/header %>`  is causing the above error.
i would really appreciate if someone could help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [correct syntax](https://ejs.co/#docs) for includes is:

```
<%- include('partials/header'); %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. this is the correct syntax and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your include syntax is correct trying it out from index.ejs in the views folder. Maybe relative path is incorrect from the profile.ejs view depending on your app structure.

Docs here. [ejs includes](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#includes)

Comment: I have already checked properly that every thing about the path is correct. Thanks for your response.